# Where can I find some Nelson Sauvin hops?

Tags: hops

I've been hearing about Nelson Sauvin hops for awhile now, and have read in other forums about people procuring some and using them... but I haven't been able to find them anywhere.  All my usual suspects don't stock them.  Anyone know where I can get these without flying over to New Zealand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a great source of organic Nelson Sauvin hops here in the US:  7 Bridges in Santa Cruz-- breworganic.com -- has them.

Comment: Glad to hear that you've finally tracked some down without having to get them posted from abroad!

Answer (score 1):

Hop & Grape in the UK have some listed on their website - http://bit.ly/8LWW4r Their website makes it look like they ship internationally if you're not based in the UK.

Comment: I've also found the following site:  www.craftbrewer.com.au that sells whole-hop Nelson as well as pellets.  I've ordered from both and will followup with the results re: freshness, etc.

Comment: I received the hops in great condition and quite fresh from Hop & Grape relatively quickly.  I've not yet received my craftbrewer.com.au order though, despite their rapid delivery claims.

Comment: The craftbrewer.com.au hops came in after approx 2 weeks in excellent condition/freshness.

Answer (score 0):

You can get in touch with NZ Hops and buy direct from the source!
http://www.nzhops.co.nz/contacts.html